# How to use HTTP Auth with resque web interface?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, resque

I have a standalone resque worker queue und would like to monitor it using the included web interface without any rails applications involved.

I manage my processes via foreman, my Procfile looking like this:

```
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work
web: bundle exec resque-web --foreground --app-dir /home/xxxx --server thin --port 5678 --no-launch
```

The generated upstart script for web looks like this:

```
start on starting resque_cmd_runner-web
stop on stopping resque_cmd_runner-web
respawn

env PORT=5100
env PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin'
env GEM_PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global'
env QUEUE='*'
env RESQUE_WEB_HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USER='xxxx'
env RESQUE_WEB_HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD='zzzz'

setuid xxxx

chdir /home/famulus/resque_cmd_runner

exec bundle exec resque-web --foreground --app-dir /home/famulus/resque_cmd_runner --server thin --port 5678 --no-launch
```

However, the environment variables for the HTTP BASIC AUTH are ignored. I figure they just work in the resque-web gem and not in the interface included with resque.

How can I get HTTP AUTH for the included app?